# Typescript: issue with async await promise.all looping through all results

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, promise

Having an issue with this result set due to it being type unknown. I've tried several different things but keep getting the same error and not sure what to do. Thanks for any help!

Here is the error message -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:153:47
    at step (C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:14:53)
    at C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:4:12)
    at C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:144:60
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at searchUsers (C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:144:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\TS\mytask\src\helloworld.js:173:13)
Promise { <rejected> [] }
(node:37216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: [object Array]
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:37216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:37216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Code -

```
    function searchUsers(filterText: string): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
       let People: IPersonaProps[] = [];
       try { 
          const tempPeople = await this.props.context.webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords("systemuser?$select=fullname,internalemailaddress,systemuserid");

          await Promise.all(tempPeople.entities.map((entity: any ) =>{
          People.push({ "text": entity.fullname, "secondaryText": entity.internalemailaddress, "id" : entity.systemuserid }); //change fieldname if values are different           
          }));
          resolve(People);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(People);
      }
    });
   }
```

Currently this works fine for 1 result, but when I try to get back a collection of results and loop through them to push to the People array, I always keep getting the same error.

Thanks again!

Comment: Is the code correctly formatted. Getting error when pasted it onto editor.

Comment: `}
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(People);
      }` where is the opening `{` for this?

Comment: missed the opening try. Sorry - had to remove some other stuff from the code that didn't need to share. So was trying to strip it down to the core issue.

Comment: your map function should return `entity`...

Comment: Ok updated the code and error message better - sorry about that. As I said, was trying to strip it down to the bare issue I was getting.

Comment: The error has been thrown at `const tempPeople = await this.props.context...`

Comment: There's a few issues I have with this code: (1) you have an async promise resolver which is usually a code smell (2) your `function searchUsers` might not be in the correct context unless you've done `this.searchUsers = this.searchUsers.bind(this)` in the constructor (which is not clear here). (3) You are using `map` but in there you are doing a `push` to an array and not mapping anything. (4) you are using `Promise.all` but `tempPeople.entities.map` does not return an array of promises (or of anything)

Comment: (5) your return type of `IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]>` is impossible since you are returning a promise so it will always return a Promise and never `IPersonalProps[]`. (6) There is no clear value in returning a promise in the function, you can just make the function itself `async` and do the inner code normally (assuming you fix issues (2) and (3)). An async function will return a promise without you needing to do it explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a member function of a class you have declared but have not initialized hence `this` being undefined. To confirm please add the code of how you are using your class...

```
private _searchUsers(filterText: string): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      let People: IPersonaProps[] = [];
      
      // This is a reference to a class
      const tempPeople = await this.props.context.webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords("systemuser?$select=fullname,internalemailaddress,systemuserid");

      // Need to make the callback function async so that it becomes an array of promises
      await Promise.all(tempPeople.entities.map(async (entity: any ) => {
        People.push({ "text": entity.fullname, "secondaryText": entity.internalemailaddress, "id" : entity.systemuserid }); //change fieldname if values are different           
      }));
      resolve(People);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(People);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Here's how I was able to get it working. Thanks for the help!

```
private _searchUsers(filterText: string): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
  let People: IPersonaProps[] = [];
  
  const config = new WebApiConfig("9.1");

  const options: string = "?$select=fullname,internalemailaddress,systemuserid";

  retrieveMultiple(config, "systemusers", options)
.then(
    (results) => {
        const People: IPersonaProps[] = [];            
        for (const record of results.value) {              
          People.push({ "text": record.fullname, "secondaryText": record.internalemailaddress, "id" : record.systemuserid }); 
          resolve(People);
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        reject(People);
        console.log(error);
    }        
   );
  });
};
```